# What's the proper data structure for simple configuration parameters in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, configuration, yaml

I need a data structure (C language) to represent configuration parameters and it would be easy to manipulate: insert, delete, look-up, etc. I think hash is too heavy, because the configuration parameters are just some hierarchy mapped key-value pairs, and most likely not more than 10. So what's the best data structure to store these configuration parameters.

====================

actually I am parsing configuration parameters from yaml file, so the point is how to store the values parsed from yaml file, and easy to look-up any values by key?

Answer (score 0):

If the set of config variables is small and not likely to change, the most straightforward (but least flexible) way would be simply to declare the right set of global variables, and then use the yaml reader to set them.  Ie, something like

```
int config1;
int config2;
...
parse_yaml_file(char *file) {
    // arrange to set config1, config2, ...
}
```

Otherwise, I think there's nothing wrong with using a hash table for something simple like this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a tree. Something similar to this maybe:

```
struct ConfTreeNode {
    char *key;
    int value;
    ConfTreeNode *child;
    ConfTreeNode *next;
};
```